# Dapper throwing invalid cast exception when using strongly-typed query parameters with Sybase ASE

Tags: c#, dapper

As the question title states, I'm getting `Specified cast is not valid` exceptions even though my stored proc returns an `int` and a `DateTime` and my class defines it the same.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get; set;}
}
```

When I execute this query:

> var results = connection.Query("spGetFoo", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

I get the following 2 exceptions:

```
InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
DataException: Error parsing column 1 (Id=1 - Decimal)

InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
DataException: Error parsing column 2 (CreatedDate=Mar  7 2012  5:52:08:276PM - String)
```

If I modify `Foo`'s properties from `int` to `decimal` and `DateTime` to `string` it properly populates the values. But, this introduces an extra step of defining another class which holds the correct variable types and then mapping from `Foo` to the new class.

I also tried going through `GetTypeDeserializer` in the Dapper source to see what's going on but I'm not very familiar with IL emit.

Comment: are you sure spGetFoo returns as int and datetime? can you show the SQL and maybe the columns definitions?

Comment: Sure would be nice to see that Stored Proc....

Answer (score 1):

maybe the problem is in the Stored procedure, but in the meantime you can use

```
public class Foo
{
    private decimal _dbId;
    public decimal DbId 
    { 
        get { return _dbId; }
        set 
        { 
            _dbId = value;
            _id =(int)value;
        }
    }
    private String _dbCreadtedDate;
    public String DbCreadtedDate 
    { 
        get { return _dbCreadtedDate; }
        set 
        {
            _dbCreadtedDate = value;
            _createdDate = DateTime.Parse(_dbCreadtedDate);
        }
    }
    private int _id;
    public int Id 
    { 
        get { return _id; } 
        set { _id = value; _dbId = value; } 
    }
    private DateTime _createdDate;
    public DateTime CreatedDate 
    { 
        get { return _createdDate; } 
        set { _createdDate = value; _dbCreadtedDate = value.ToString(); } 
    }
}
```